# Magento header block in layout

Tags: magento-1.5, magento

I have downloaded a custom module in magento that loads a block into layout using a reference:

```
<reference name="content">
    <block type="ibanner/content_top" name="ibanner_content_top" template="my_ibanner/content/top.phtml" before="-"/>
    <block type="ibanner/content_bottom" name="ibanner_content_bottom" template="my_ibanner/content/bottom.phtml" after="-"/>
</reference>
```

This code is working fine. However if i use the header refence the banner is not displayed on the page i can't figure out why...

If i use the page_two_columns_left layout and reference the left name layout block, the banner shows up, i can't tell the diference between the blocks to make some of them load the baner and others wont.

If somewone can help me out with this i will really apreciate it.

Regards.

Comment: "However if i use the header reference the banner is not displayed" is not precise enough for someone to answer your question.  What's the code you use to achieve what's in the quotes, and how are you adding this code to the system?

Comment: Hello Alan,

Sorry if i didn't make myself clear. The problem was pointed out by Ben. The header block didn't contain any instruction to load the aditional blocks so the banner wasn't loaded. The header block i am using is the default used by magento.

Cheers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Part of "injecting" a block in different routes depends on the parent block. "content" and "left" are `core/text_list` blocks (`Mage_Core_Block_Text_List`), which by design do not use templates and simply render all child blocks. If a block uses a template however, you must (should) take two steps:

1. Setup the parent/child relationship. Again, in the code above, the two ibanner blocks are being declared as children on the "content" block
2. Customize the parent block's associated template with the rendering instructions necessary for the child block, e.g. `<?php echo $this->getChildHtml("ibanner_content_top") ?>`.

Note that template files which contain an empty `getChildHtml()` call will render all child blocks.

Comment: Thank you very much for your help. I didn't realize the diference you pointed out. If i just add an empty getChildHtml() the block gets loaded in the header block. Regards.

Comment: don´t have any solution to add the block by the layout with the <action method="setChild,append,unset, etc" inherit of Mage_Core_Block_Abstract???? i can unset all block and made a setTemplate, and in my new template have a copy of header.phtml and append my new block. Thanks ben